# Disabling add, edit, delete buttons

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I would like to add dynamic buttons in my Angular asp.net core web api. When the status of product is "Z", functionality like add, edit and delete should be not visible.

I have one method which works but in second case I do not know how to use it. Please find below example of working method:

Component.service.ts

```
    getDisabledAddEditDel(model:Component,mode: string)
{
    if(model && mode != 'View' && mode !='Add' && model.StatusOfProduct === 'Z')
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In above case StatusOfProduct exist in model Component. I would like to use this method in a second case but in second model, StatusOfProduct does not exist. How can I use StatusOfProduct from Component in other service (model). Is there any other way than adding StatusOfProduct to my second service and model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the condition directly in the html. The [disabled] directive if set to true will disable the given button.

```
 <button [disabled]="model && mode != 'View' && mode !='Add' 
                && model.StatusOfProduct === 'Z'" (click)="add()">ADD</button>
```

You can also achieve the same result with your function

```
      <button [disabled]="getDisabledAddEditDel(model,mode)"
                 (click)="add()">ADD</button>
```